# Start a python interpreter with local object included

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to start a python interpreter after performing a few operations to make it more easy for the user. So far, I have a skeleton of what I want.

```
class ApiManager(object):
  def __init__(self, username, password, version='v1'):
    self.base_url = 'http://localhost:3000/api/' + version + '/{endpoint}'

    login = requests.post(self.base_url.format(endpoint='login'), {
      'user': username, 'password': password
    }).json()['data']

    self.headers = {
      'X-Auth-Token': login['authToken'],
      'X-User-Id': login['userId']
    }

  def get(self, endpoint):
    " example method "
    return requests.get(self.base_url.format(endpoint))

if __name__ == '__main__':
  Api = ApiManager('user@user.org', 'password')
  code.interact(banner="use Api.<Crud Command> to do a method")
```

However, what I am wondering is, *how can I import this local into my `code.interact`*?

I've tried `local=Api` but that does not work, saying `TypeError: exec() arg 2 must be a dict, not ApiInterpreter`. I've tried using `Api.__dict__()` but that does not work either. I was also thinking it might be possible to subclass `code.InteractiveConsole`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
code.interact(banner="use Api.<Crud Command> to do a method", local={"Api": Api})
```